# Working example of RATreeView in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift2

Can anybody please provide a working example of [RATreeView](https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView) in a Swift 2 project?

I have been unsuccessful in trying to get it working myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a small example:

```
class TreeViewController:
    UIViewController,
    RATreeViewDataSource,
    RATreeViewDelegate
{
    private var treeView: RATreeView!
    private let xibName = "TreeViewSampleCell"

    override dynamic func viewDidLoad() {
        treeView = RATreeView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        treeView.delegate = self
        treeView.dataSource = self

        treeView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(treeView)
        treeView.reloadData()

        treeView.registerNib(
            UINib(nibName: xibName, bundle: nil),
            forCellReuseIdentifier: xibName)
    }

    func treeView(treeView: RATreeView!, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject!) -> Int {
        return item ? 3 : 0
    }

    func treeView(treeView: RATreeView!, cellForItem item: AnyObject!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        let cell = treeView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(xibName) as! TreeViewCell
        ...
          return cell
    }

    func treeView(treeView: RATreeView!, child index: Int, ofItem item: AnyObject!) -> AnyObject! {
        return index
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I am trying with the RATree view using objective-c but it is not calling the "cellForItem" method of RATree View so can you please tell me what may be the reason.Thanks.

Comment: You have the datasource set?

Comment: yes it is calling all other delegate method but not calling only "cellForItem" method

Comment: Please you post your obj-c version of cellForItem.

Comment: @Tapani i have successfully implemented this but when i expand cell my child cell reposition on second click...first time it is at same position of its parent